# Android Studio / Gradle can't find imported component

Tags: android, gradle

A project I'm developing at work has the following component imports going on. Names changed to protect proprietary info.

#### `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

```
lib_includedLibrary=/home/myuser/includedLibrary/lib_includedLibrary
```

#### Project's `settings.gradle`

```
include 'includedLibrary'
project (':includedLibrary').projectDir = new File(lib_includedLibrary)

include ':myAppModule'
```

#### In the module's `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile project(':includedLibrary')
}
```

#### Problem

Android Studio doesn't seem to be finding my `gradle.properties` file. No matter what I do to point it at this dependency, it can't find it.

```
Gradle 'MyProject' project refresh failed
    Error: Could not find property 'lib_includedLibrary' on settings 'MyProject'.
```

When it fails in this way, the project's `settings.gradle` gets marked up in the IDE as if *none* of the syntax or symbols is correct.

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'include'
```

I have already verified that it's really at that location, and I've even opened the library (we develop it, too) in AS and it opens successfully.

This same setup *works fine* on my work laptop (running AS 1.5.1) but fails on the development VM I set up at home (running AS 2.1).

I have been beating my head against this for a couple of days now and still can't figure out why it works in one place and not in another.

Anyone have any ideas of "gotchas" to check, or environmental differences that might be a factor here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out and now I just feel stupid.

I had installed a separate Gradle instance and had put its location into the "Service directory path" configuration screen in Android Studio. When comparing to my working instance on my work laptop, this was still set to `/home/myuser/.gradle`. Changing this back to `/home/myuser/.gradle` on the non-working VM instance caused it to pick up the `gradle.properties` file properly and import the dependency.

Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

please try to import you Library the Android studio "way" :

go to File > New > Import Module  >>> select your Library folder from your Computer and name it `includedLibrary`

keep `compile project(':includedLibrary')` in you dependencies

Comment: If my current setup was not viable then it wouldn't already be working on another machine. In the past when a new developer has joined we have simply instructed them to set up a `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file, open the root project, and AS was smart enough to find the resolve these dependencies. Now suddenly it is not.